# the multithread not working with me

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I have to write program that finds the sum of a 2D array of int,
I coded every thing as I know and there is no syntax error but when I use someways to check my code the thread is not working at all but sometimes work some of thread not all of them 
I put the number 1 to check the summation
and I put lock to make sure not two of thread in same method of summation only for make sure 
and the n for see how much time it's join the add method

```
public class extend extends Thread {

    int a, b;
    private static int sum = 0;
    static int n;
    boolean lock;
    int[][] arr;

    public extend() {
        arr = new int[45][45];
        for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 45; j++)
                arr[i][j] = 1;
        }
        n = 0;
        lock = false;

    }


    public extend(int a, int b) {
        arr = new int[45][45];
        for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 45; j++)
                arr[i][j] = 1;
        }
        n = 0;
        lock = false;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }


    public void run() {
        add(a, b);
    }


    public void add(int st, int e) {

        n++;
        while (lock) ;
        lock = true;
        int sums = 0;
        synchronized (this) {

            for (int i = st; i < e; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 45; j++) {
                    sums += arr[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        sum = sums;
        lock = false;
    }


    public int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long ss = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new extend(0, 9));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new extend(9, 18));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new extend(18, 27));
        Thread t4 = new Thread(new extend(27, 36));
        Thread t5 = new Thread(new extend(36, 45));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
        t5.start();

        long se = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("The sum for 45*45 array is: " + sum);
        System.out.println("time start;" + (se - ss));
        System.out.print(n);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to say, but there's so much wrong with this code, it's hard to point at one problem:

1. You start your threads, but you don't wait for them to finish using `.join()`
2. Extending `Thread` when you actually meant implementing `Runnable`
3. Using busy waiting in your thread with `while (true)`
4. Using of `static int`for counting

But, if there's only one thing you must fix, wait for your threads:

```
    t1.join();
    ...
    t5.join();
```

Comment: thank you  it's working now correctly and forgive me, I'm still student and I just take the os course and the threads object ,thank you agin for the great help❤️

Comment: and please let me ask you another question: could I coding the multithreading in eclipse or should I do it in the terminal , and to see the execution time did I but the method in the right positions

Comment: It doesn't matter in what you code. It will be executed just the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your lockout of the `sum` variable may not even result in a speedup while taking into account the overhead of creating `Thread`s, but your main problem is you are not adding `sums` to `sum`.

---

Change:

`sum = sums;`

to:

`sum += sums;`

This will make your code work for **some of the time**.  It is not guaranteed to work and will sometimes output weird results like 1620 instead of 2025.  You should learn more about how to properly handle multithreading, race conditions, and atomic locks.

Comment: thank you for that's  before I only use sum and when I recognized there is deferent summation I added sums to divided the summation